# skipping incompatible eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, path, mingw, libraries

I get a compile error on eclipse.

```
skipping incompatible C:\Users\khhwork\Desktop\test\test\Datastore\lib/libpq.dll when searching for -lpq
```

I have no idea why or even how to be able to change that last / into a \ in the pathname.

I have been changing and exploring all the settings with no success.

thanks,
Kaven

Comment: The / vs \ is a red herring. Windows can handle either. From searching other posts on this topic this looks like a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue. I.e. you are looking for one version but you have the other version installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Win32 API used by Windows applications both accepts the / and \ separators for directories, and the error reported at compile time looks like something different. Probably the libpq.dll you have is not for the same platform you are compiling the rest of the application for (e.g., you compile a 64-bit application and the DLL is a 32-bit one, or the opposite, or you're compiling for another platform like ARM and the DLL is for x86... can be anything like this).